# Passing the same props while rendering different elements conditionally in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have a React Component named Chart. I want to render different charts in it based on the prop passed from their parent, but having the exactly same config. What is the best way to do it?

```javascript
class Chart extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  state = {
    chartData: {
      // some data here 
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      this.props.type === 'line' ?
      { <Line
        data={this.state.chartData}
        options={{
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Cities I\'ve lived in',
            fontSize: 25
          },
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
              fontColor: '#000'
            }
          }
        }}
      /> } : this.props.type === 'bar' ?
      { <Bar
          //same stuff here as <Line />
        />
      } : this.props.type === 'pie' ?
      { <Pie
          //same stuff here as <Line />
        /> }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Don't think it matters since the question is generic, but I'm using *react-chartjs-2* / *chart.js 2* library for rendering charts.

Note: I've tried using a variable name in place of Line/Bar/Pie, but it doesn't work if I'm using JSX or rendering a non-html tag. Better ways to solve it while using JSX and non-html tags are also welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

- Use stateless component, in your example you are not using state.
- Use `switch` instead of `if` statements.

Your new component, `...chart` are the destructured props. Read more about destructuring on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
// Chart.js - new component

export const Chart = ({ type, ...chart }) => { 
  switch(type) {
    case 'line':
      return <Line {...chart} />
    case 'bar':
      return <Bar {...chart} />
    case 'pie':
      return <Pie {...chart} />
    default:
     return null;
  }
}
```

Example usage

```
// App.js 

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Chart type="line" options={optionsObject} whateverProp="whatever" />
      <Chart type="bar" options={optionsObject} whateverProp="whatever" />
      <Chart type="pie" options={optionsObject} whateverProp="whatever" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Chart extends Component {
  components = {
    Line: Line,
    Bar: Bar,
    Pie: Pie
  };
  render() {
    const TagName = this.components[this.props.tag || 'Line'];
    return
      <TagName
        data={this.state.chartData}
        options={{
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Cities I\'ve lived in',
          fontSize: 25
        },
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'right',
          labels: {
            fontColor: '#000'
          }
        }
      }}
    />
  }
}
export default Chart;

// Call MyComponent using prop tag with required prop Line or Bar or Pie
<Chart tag='Line' />
```

NOTE:- You could create it as a stateless functional component as well.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have each chart as a component, so you can do chart's specific configuration in that component and your code will be more close to React codes modularity goal, so for Line chart as example:

```
class LineChart extends Component {

const chartLegend = {
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
            labels: {
              fontColor: '#000'
            }};

const chartTitle = {
            display: true,
            text: 'Cities I\'ve lived in',
            fontSize: 25
          };
const chartOptions = {
          title: chartTitle ,
          legend: chartLegend           
        }

  render(){
    return(
      <Line
        data={this.props.chartData}
        options={chartOptions }
      /> 
    );
  }
}
```

Now for chat Component as container component you can use switch case or guard conditions as @loelsonk also said, I prefer to have guard conditions besides switch:

```
class Chart extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  state = {
    chartData: {
      // some data here 
    }
  }

  render(){
    if (this.props.type === 'line')
      return <LineChart chartData={...}/>; 
    if (this.props.type === 'bar')
      return <BarChart chartData={...}/>;
    if (this.props.type === 'pie')
      return <PieChart chartData={...}/>;      
  }
}
```

this way you can easily replace any chart implementation any time that needed.